# Custom metrics missing when using dotnet-monitor

Tags: c#, .net, metrics, .net-6.0

I am trying to set up the `dotnet-monitor` to get Prometheus style metrics on the [`metrics` endpoint](https://github.com/dotnet/dotnet-monitor/blob/main/documentation/api/metrics.md), but I cannot get my custom metrics reported through the API.

I made an application from the example in [Collect metrics from .NET documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/diagnostics/metrics-collection). Using `dotnet-counters monitor -p <ProcessID> HatCo.HatStore` The result is the expected:

```
[HatCo.HatStore]
    hats-sold (Count / 1 sec)                          4
```

Trying to get it through the `dotnet-monitor` does not include this counter, neither in the `metrics` or the `livemetrics` endpoint.

The settings.json ([as described in the documentation](https://github.com/dotnet/dotnet-monitor/blob/main/documentation/configuration.md#metrics-configuration)) used by `dotnet-monitor` looks like this:

```json
{
    "$schema": "https://aka.ms/dotnet-monitor-schema",
    "DefaultProcess": {
        "Filters": [{
            "Key": "ProcessName",
            "Value": "ToBeMeasured"
        }]
    },
    "Metrics": {
        "Providers": [
            {"ProviderName": "HatCo.HatStore"}
        ]
    }
}
```

And I have played with the parameter `"IncludeDefaultProviders": false`, which works as expected (the systemruntime metrics are not produced).

Do I need to register the "HatCo.HatStore" somewhere in the application?

Answer (score 0):

According to the doc [here](https://github.com/dotnet/dotnet-monitor/blob/main/documentation/configuration.md#custom-metrics)

You need to add it like

```json
{
  "Metrics": {
    "Providers": [
      {
        "ProviderName": "Microsoft-AspNetCore-Server-Kestrel",
        "CounterNames": [
          "connections-per-second",
          "total-connections"
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```